# How to use C++ htslib to read VCF contig name and size?

Tags: c++, htslib

A typical VCF file has:

```
##contig=<ID=chr1,length=248956422>
##contig=<ID=chr2,length=242193529>
```

I would like to use `htslib` in C++ to read it. My attempt:

```
htsFile *fp = bcf_open("my.vcf", "r");
bcf_hdr_t *hdr = bcf_hdr_read(fp);
```

In https://github.com/samtools/htslib/blob/develop/htslib/vcf.h, I'm not able to find a function that can do that for me.

How to read `chr1` and `248956422` in C++?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the (internal) function `bcf_hdr_parse_line` does that. It returns an object x of type `bcf_hrec_t*`, for which `strcmp(x->key, "contig") == 0)` for your lines. You can then access the `x->keys` and `x->vals`. Untested.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Can I use it externally properly? Without hacking?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by “properly”. Since the API isn’t properly documented anyway, the distinction between external and internal functions is somewhat fluid. It might break with future versions of htslib, if that’s what you’re concerned about.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yeah. Breaking with future versions is my concern. If I see don't any other alternative, I might go with that or just parse the file myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```c
#include "htslib/vcf.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    htsFile *fp;
    bcf_hdr_t *hdr;
    bcf_idpair_t *ctg;
    int i;
    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: print-ctg <in.vcf>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fp = vcf_open(argv[1], "r");
    hdr = vcf_hdr_read(fp);
    ctg = hdr->id[BCF_DT_CTG];
    for (i = 0; i < hdr->n[BCF_DT_CTG]; ++i)
        printf("%s\t%d\n", ctg[i].key, ctg[i].val->info[0]);
    bcf_hdr_destroy(hdr);
    vcf_close(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

On stability: this use has been in htslib forever. In general, functions/structs/variables in the public headers are meant to be stable. However, there is no guarantee that future versions will always keep the same APIs.